# I keep getting this error whilst using the Keyboard in LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

I need your help.
I keep getting this exception:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Keyboard must be created before you can read events
    at org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard.next(Keyboard.java:467)
    at oregon.src.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:15)
    at oregon.client.Oregon.start(Oregon.java:19)
    at oregon.client.Oregon.main(Oregon.java:84)
```

I don't know how to fix it. I was posting a question earlier and someone helped me but then it led into this.
Here's the code for the (oregon.src.Controller):

```
package oregon.src;

import oregon.client.Oregon;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

public class Controller {
    public Oregon oregon;

    public Controller(Oregon oregon) throws LWJGLException {
        this.oregon = oregon;

        while (Keyboard.next()) {
            if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
                if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_F11) {
                    oregon.setFullscreen();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code for (oregon.client.Oregon):

```
package oregon.client;

import oregon.src.Controller;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

public class Oregon {
    public static DisplayMode normal = new DisplayMode(640, 640);

    public Controller controller;

    public static boolean fullscreen = false;

    public void start() {
        try {
            controller = new Controller(this);
        } catch (LWJGLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            stop(e);
        }

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            events();
            Display.update();
        }

        Display.destroy();
    }

    public void events() {
        try {
            new Controller(this);
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setFullscreen() {
        try {
            if (!fullscreen) {
                Display.setFullscreen(true);
                fullscreen = true;
            } else if (fullscreen) {
                Display.setDisplayMode(normal);
                fullscreen = false;
            }
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            stop(e);
        }
    }

    public static void create() throws LWJGLException {        
        if (fullscreen) {
            Display.setFullscreen(true);
        } else if (!fullscreen) {
            Display.setDisplayMode(normal);
        }

        Keyboard.create();
        Display.create();
    }

    public void stop() {
        System.exit(0);
        Display.destroy();
    }

    public void stop(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
        Display.destroy();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Oregon oregon = new Oregon();
        oregon.start();
    }
}
```

If someone could help me, I would be most grateful.
Thank you.

**EDIT:-**
Now I'm getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Display must be created.
at org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard.create(Keyboard.java:319)
at oregon.src.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:19)
at oregon.client.Oregon.start(Oregon.java:19)
at oregon.client.Oregon.main(Oregon.java:84)
```

Answer (score 3):

As error says - you need to create `keyboard`

```
public Controller(Oregon oregon) throws LWJGLException {
        this.oregon = oregon;


        Keyboard.create(); // <- add this here.

        while (Keyboard.next()) {
            if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
                if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_F11) {
                    oregon.setFullscreen();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

From [API](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Keyboard.html#create%28%29):

> "Create" the keyboard. The display must first have been created. The
>   reason for this is so the keyboard has a window to "focus" in.

EDIT: seems like you can't initialize them both at the same time, so try with this approach - cover initializing `Keyboard` in that if statement:

```
   if ( !Keyboard.isCreated() && !getPrivilegedBoolean("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.nokeyboard") ) {
                try {
                    Keyboard.create();
                } catch (LWJGLException e) {
                    if ( LWJGLUtil.DEBUG ) {
                        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    } else {
                        LWJGLUtil.log("Failed to create Keyboard: " + e);
                    }
                }
            }
```

[Here is posted similar source code, that seems to be working fine.](http://massapi.com/source/lwjgl-source-2.7.1/src/java/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.java.html)

Comment: Now I get an IllegalStateException. Help please! Sorry forgot the text after. "Only one LWJGL context may be instantiated at any one time."

Comment: @Taylor Golden, I can't read in your mind. Post fixed code and stack trace in question edit.

Comment: I have now @dantuch, please reply, I really need your help! :P

Comment: @Taylor Golden, Edited my answer.

Comment: I put the error in the question again || I changed it, although it looks similar

Comment: @Taylor Golden, did you remove `Display.create();`? It have to stay somewhere to make things work - read your stack trace.

Comment: I re added the `display.create()` above the `keyboard.create()` and got the error from before, now I put `display.create()` below and now I get the error that I'm putting in the question.

Comment: Are you still there? Please, this means a lot to me.

Comment: @Taylor, have you eveer tried my first solution? and putting keyboard.start in **exact same** place as I did?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the error, initialize and create the display in the main function like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
    Display.create();
    Oregon oregon = new Oregon();
    oregon.start();
}
```

(Add try/catch where needed/wanted). That worked for me in a quick test.